# awk- print a column in different rows

Tags: bash, awk

I have this simplified table of numbers constituted by 2 columns and several rows. The point here is for each column, take the values and order them in rows so that in each row there are 4 values. This file.txt:

```
1   2   
1   2   
1   2   
1   2   
1   2   
1   2   
1   2   
1   2   
1   2
```

And this is the result that I want:

```
1    1    1    1
1    1    1    1    
1   

2    2    2    2    
2    2    2    2    
2
```

I do the following, creating a script.awk for clarity.

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Where script.awk is

```
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
     printf "%s" (NR %4==0 ? RS:FS), $i;}
```

But it does not wok. I know that the following command works for one column, but I do not understand why it does not work for a loop in each column.

```
{printf "%s" (NR %4==0 ? RS:FS), $1;}
```

If poossible, I would like an explanation of the sommands used, as I am new to this language. Thanks!

Comment: You can do `awk '{print $1}' file | xargs -n4` and then the same with 2nd column.

Comment: @fedorqui Nice, I knew there was a trick like that but I couldn't remember it!

Answer (score 3):

I would post a generic solution:

```
awk  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i,NR]=$i; }END{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)
           printf "%s%s", a[i,j],(j%4==0||j==NR?"\n":" ");
    } 
}' file
```

this works for dynamic columns in your input file, e.g.:

```
kent$ cat f
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4

kent$ awk  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i,NR]=$i; }END{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)
                        printf "%s%s", a[i,j],(j%4==0||j==NR?"\n":" ");
    } 
}' f
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2
3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3
3
4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4
4
```

you just need to change the `4` to control how many cols in your output. it is also easy to be put as an argument with `awk -v cols="$var" ...`

Comment: +1 nice! If you like golf: `(j%4==0||j==NR?"\n":" ")` -> `(j%4&&j<NR?FS:RS)`.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you, I am really happy to have the vote from you. :-)

Comment: You get them a lot, I usually just don't comment when I upvote. So you can be happy all the time :-).

Comment: @EdMorton You should comment at least on my answers so that I know I've got it right. `;)`

Comment: @jaypal - when you get one right I'll let you know ;-). Just kidding of course.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '{a[$1]++; b[$2]++} END{for (i=1; i<=a[$1]; i++) printf "%s%s", $1, (i%4)?FS:ORS ; 
    print ""; for (i=1; i<[$2]; i++) printf "%s%s", $2, (i%4)?FS:ORS; print ""}' file
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, use `awk` and `sort`:

```
cat file|awk '{printf("%s\n%s\n",$1,$2)}'|sort|awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}
    {if(NR==1){l=$1};if($1!=l){printf("\n");NR=1};
    print $1;if(NR%4==0){printf("\n")};l=$1}'
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that awk goes through each line (record) one at a time, so the loop in your block will apply the first field in the first line, the second field, then move on to the next line. This doesn't do what you want, as you need all the elements of the first field before you can do anything.

One option is to build an array of both fields, then print them when you get to the end of the file:

```
awk 'function p(a) { s=""; for(i=1;i<=NR;++i) s=s a[i] (i%4==0 ? RS:FS); print s }
{ a[NR]=$1; b[NR]=$2 }
END { p(a); p(b) }' file
```